# my text does not apear on the screen after I enter it in on javascript prompt

Tags: javascript, html, dom

hey guys doing this tutorial again on JavaScript. I noticed that when I click the button I don't see any text after I enter in the new items. Do any of you know why. The border is there from my css so I know its being entered in, anyway here is my code so far.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

    <title>To do list with html and javascript</title>
    <style>
    ul { list-style: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; width: 400px;}
    li { border: 4px solid #ccc; background: #eee; padding: 10px 15px; color: #000; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
<h1>To Do List</h1>
<p><button id="btnAdd">click here!</button></p> 

<ul id="todolist">
</ul>

</ul>


<script src="todo.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and

```
function addNewItem(list, itemText){
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = "itemText";


    list.appendChild(listItem);
}


var btnNew= document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
    var itemText = prompt("what is your task?")
    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html mark up is wrongly posted . There is an extra `ul` there.

More over the js code must be like :

```
function addNewItem(list, itemText){
    var listItem = document.createElement("li");
    listItem.innerText = itemText;
    list.appendChild(listItem);
}

var btnNew= document.getElementById("btnAdd");
btnNew.onclick = function() {
    var itemText = prompt("what is your task?")
    addNewItem(document.getElementById("todolist"), itemText);
};
```

Next find the working solution in this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/LRyKd/1/

When you give `itemText` as `'itemText'` then itemText becomes a string and that constant string gets appended instead of the text you are entering.  That's why it was not working for you .

Comment: Hey I used the fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/LRyKd/1/ and found out that it works for me on internet explorer but not on Firefox. I had the HTML file loaded default to Firefox so I right clicked on it and changed its properties to default load with internet explorer and now it will show text when I click enter after prompt.

Answer (score 4):

```
listItem.innerText = "itemText"; // This is a string
```

Should be

```
listItem.innerText = itemText; // This is the parameter
```

You also seem to have an extra `</ul>` end-tag.

Comment: what difference it will make

Comment: @user2502227 The first is using a string (in the same way as `"what is your task?"`), so it will always be the text `itemText`. The second is the actual parameter with the text from the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The itemText in the addNewItem mehod should not be enclosed in quotes.

```
listItem.innerText = itemText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple misstate remove the second /ul